# Bypassing inclusion of different directives faster or negligible?

Tags: c#, performance, directive, using-directives

Does bypassing the use of a directive make any real difference in the execution of an application? Obviously my below example isn't going to really matter as it is so small, but if this application were on a much, MUCH larger scale, would it make a performance improvement? I've often wondered about this and I am writing an application where execution speed is going to be fairly important.

No directives...

```
namespace Generation
{
    class GeoData
    {
        public System.String geoCode { get; set; }
        public System.String geoName { get; set; }
        public System.String geoType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Opposed to...

using System;

```
namespace Generation
{
    class GeoData
    {
        public String geoCode { get; set; }
        public String geoName { get; set; }
        public String geoType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same difference. The compiler resolves the actual method calls and classes, and even removes unused using statements for you. They both compile to the same code.